# Android Eclipse not working after Java Update how do I fix it?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

after Updating Java a couple days ago to version 8 update 31, I couldn't get my Android Eclipse to work. Every time I open it this comes up http://gyazo.com/12547a9085db3cfd8da258eac1e86c12. I've tried many other questions which usually refer to just Eclipse, and this particular error, which helped me get regular Eclipse working by typing in:

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/javaw.exe
```

Into the eclipse.ini file, but the same didn't work for the one in android eclipse.
Thanks in advance!

.ini file for Android Eclipse(This was all in one line, and I took the -vm line out that I initially added in):-

```
-startup
 plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
 plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
 com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
 256m
--launcher.defaultAction
 openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

.ini file for normal Eclipse(this includes the -vm line I added in):-

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Comment: can you post full .ini file

Comment: @Boopathi ^ was that what you were asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you change this to version 1.7 in your adt eclipse.ini?
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6

Every link I view on the issue addresses 32 bit and 64 bit java.  The screen shot that you posted reads adt-bundle-windows-x86_64.  On the next line -os win32 and in subsequent library paths shows some capatibility efforts with 32 bit windows.

Check your cpu, adt version and java version for the same bit size, in this case 64 bit.

Also, make sure all your paths are pointing to your jdk directory and not your jre directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/javaw.exe
```

keep above code as first two line of eclipse.ini file.Then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i just needed to re install [jdk7u79](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) and eclipse works again.